# Rails adding "belongs to" to "has many" and storing results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, model, controller, belongs-to

I'm new to Stackoverflow & rails, but hello!

I've had a look around and can't quite get everything together.

I'm creating a dashboard that will allow a user to add a new client with 4 different fields. Then allowing the user to add projects, with 8 different fields to a particular client. However, I'm struggling to add a project to a client and get it to show up. I've made my code public at: https://github.com/JackStovell/revenue-dashboard.

Please rip my code to pieces & tell me where I'm going wrong so I can adjust it!

Thanks

Here's some snippets:

**Project Model:**

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :client
end
```

**Client model**

```
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :projects
end
```

**Projects Controller**

```
class ProjectsController < ApplicationController
skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
before_action :set_project, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]



# GET /projects
# GET /projects.json
def index
@projects = Project.all
@clientnav = Client.all

end

# GET /projects/1
# GET /projects/1.json
def show
@project = Project.find(params[:id])
@clientnav = Client.all
end



# GET /projects/new
def new
@project = Project.new
@client = Client.all
@clientnav = Client.all
end

# GET /projects/1/edit
def edit
 @clientnav = Client.all
 @client = Client.all
end

# POST /projects
# POST /projects.json
def create
@project = Project.new(project_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @project.save
    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @project }
  else
    format.html { render :new }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
 @clientnav = Client.all
end

# PATCH/PUT /projects/1
# PATCH/PUT /projects/1.json
def update
respond_to do |format|
  if @project.update(project_params)
    format.html { redirect_to @project, notice: 'Project was successfully   updated.' }
    format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @project }
  else
    format.html { render :edit }
    format.json { render json: @project.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
  end
  @clientnav = Client.all
  end

  # DELETE /projects/1
 # DELETE /projects/1.json
 def destroy
 @project.destroy
 respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to projects_url, notice: 'Project was successfully destroyed.' }
  format.json { head :no_content }
  end
 @clientnav = Client.all
 end

 def income
 @project.income = params[@project.billing] - params[@project.cost]
 end

private
# Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
def set_project
  @project = Project.find(params[:id])
end

# Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
def project_params
  params.require(:project).permit(:id, :name, :jobNumber, :status, :billing, :cost, :income)
end


end
```

**Clients Controller**

```
   class ClientsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token
    before_action :set_client, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]




    # GET /clients
    # GET /clients.json
    def index
      @clients = Client.all
     @clientnav = Client.all
    end



    # GET /clients/1
    # GET /clients/1.json
    def show
      @client = Client.find(params[:id])
      @projects = @client.projects
       @clientnav = Client.all
    end

    # GET /clients/new
    def new
      @client = Client.new
       @clientnav = Client.all

    end

    # GET /clients/1/edit
    def edit
       @clientnav = Client.all

    end

    # POST /clients
    # POST /clients.json
    def create
     @clientnav = Client.all
      @client = Client.new(client_params)

      respond_to do |format|
        if @client.save
          format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully created.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @client }
        else
          format.html { render :new }
          format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
    end

    # PATCH/PUT /clients/1
    # PATCH/PUT /clients/1.json
    def update
      respond_to do |format|
        if @client.update(client_params)
          format.html { redirect_to @client, notice: 'Client was successfully updated.' }
          format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @client }
        else
          format.html { render :edit }
          format.json { render json: @client.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
        end
      end
        @clientnav = Client.all
    end

    # DELETE /clients/1
    # DELETE /clients/1.json
    def destroy
      @client.destroy
      respond_to do |format|
        format.html { redirect_to clients_url, notice: 'Client was successfully destroyed.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      end

    end

    private
      # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
      def set_client
        @client = Client.find(params[:id])

      end

      # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
      def client_params
        params.require(:client).permit(:clientName, :clientOwner, :analysis, :analysis2)

      end

  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Code:

## clients_controller.rb

```
def new
  @client = Client.new
  @project = @client.projects.build
end

def create
  @client = Client.new(client_params)
  @client.save
end

def client_params
  params.require(:client).permit(:id, :client_name, ...,
   project_attributes: [:name, ...] )
end
```

## projects/_form.html.erb

```
<%= f.label :clientName %>
<%= f.text_field :clientName"%>

....
....

<%= f.fields_for :projects do |project| %>
  <%= project.label :name %>
  <%= project.text_field :name%>

  ....
  ....
<%end%>
```

## model/client.rb

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :projects
```